# Finding Out Value is Similar to any Values in List

Tags: c#, list

How would I check to find if the value `i` I'm looking at, is equal to, or in range of a number in a list?

So for example, I have a number `i = 2`, and a number `i = 2.1` in a list, and I don't want to add `i = 2` to the list, because they are fairly similar numbers. I'm having difficulty finding a clean way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're going to need to decide what "close" means in your situation.  After that it should be a simple matter of looping through the list to see if the numbers are "close".

Comment: Please define what "similar" should be in this case. Only then it's possible to have a solution.

Comment: "Similar" and "Close" are arbitrary. Say `0.5` for this case. How would I check to see if a value in a list is within that range so that I can determine whether to add that value to the list, or discard it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can check for Any similar values before adding. Expressed nicelly in LINQ:

```
var list = new List<double> { 2.1, 4, 5, 5.1 };
var i = 2;
var e = 0.5;

var hasSimilar = list.Any(x => Math.Abs(x - i) <= e);
if(!hasSimilar)
    list.Add(i);
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your quick replies! This solution works best for my case.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to test if a value is within a certain range is using [`Math.Abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2yzeea2(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, if you are looking for all numbers within `0.5` from `2`, you can find them as follows:

```
var target = 2;
var tolerance = 0.5;
var twoPlusMinusHalf = list.Where(x => Math.Abs(x-target) <= tolerance).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This..........

```
        List<double> list = new List<double>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2.1);
        list.Add(3.5);
        list.Add(4.9);
        list.Add(5);

        double i=2;

        int cnt = 0;
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            if(i==item || i==(item-0.1))
            {
                cnt = 1;
            }
        }

        if(cnt<1)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
```

Comment: Try improving your answer by adding an explanation to go along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

As Hill mentioned in their comment, you have to determine what "similar numbers" means to you and then implement that logic.

For your example, you'd do a simple `if` check to see if the numbers are in the desired range.

```
if (i >= 2 && i < 2.2)
    listName.Add(i);
```

Comment: This method only checks for a specific given value, and won't work with a wide variety of numbers.

Comment: @John this was just an example that illustrated my point using the numbers he provided. The constants in the above code could easily be changed to variables for greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<double> myList = new List<double>();
//Build list

double epsilon = 0.5;
double newValue = ...;
bool addToList = true;
foreach(double val : myList)
    if(Math.Abs(val - newValue) < epsilon)
    {
        addToList = false;
        break; //You don't need to check any further
    }

if(addToList)
    myList.Add(newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting negative numbers do not use Abs, try using Floor or Ceiling.

```
    Double i = 4;
    List<double> ListOfNumbers = new List<double>();
    Double Floored = Math.Floor(i);

    if (!ListOfNumbers.Contains(Floored))
    {//If not found add the number for later
        ListOfNumbers.Add(Floored);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom comparer like this:

```
class CloseEnough : IEqualityComparer<double>
{
    public bool Equals(double a, double b)
    {
        return Math.Abs(a - b) <= 0.5;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(double a)
    {
        return 2 * (Convert.ToInt32(a) / 2);
    }
}
```

then you can use that when creating a set:

```
var comparer = new CloseEnough();
var set = new HashSet<double>(comparer);
```

Once you've got the set, you just add elements to it, and any that are too close to existing elements are automatically rejected:

```
set.Add(1);
set.Add(1.1);
set.Add(1.6);
set.Add(2.1);
set.Add(2.11);
set.Add(10);
```

The above results in `set == { 1, 1.6, 2.11, 10 }`.

---

Note that `CloseEnough.GetHashCode()` is interesting. Two elements that are equal must have the same hash code. If you were using this in production code you'd want to test that this is always true.